# Is it possible to keep window set up when connecting via emacsclient?

Tags: window, frames, emacsclient

I love using Emacsserver and Emacsclient, as it saves all of my buffers so that if I log in via ssh and then log out, all of my buffers are saved.

However, when I log into Emacsserver after quitting from another session, the layout (for instance how many windows I have and how they are set up) is gone, and I always start from a Scratch buffer.

In the past I have used TMUX to make it so that when I reconnect to a terminal session, my Emacs session was identical to how I left it.

Even if I minimize Emacsserver before exiting `^z` upon reconnecting all of my window set up information is lost.

Is there a way to have Emacsserver remember all your window placement options?

Comment: FYI you're creating a *new frame* when you connect with emacsclient, so you wouldn't expect Emacs to set a window configuration for that frame any more than you'd expect it to do so when creating one with `C-x 5 2`. There will be solutions to the problem, but that's why it behaves this way by default.

Comment: This default behavior makes sense to me, I am really asking if there is any way that it is possible.

Comment: The `frameset` library is probably what you want to look at. As an easy manual example/demonstration, try `C-x r f a` before closing one client, and `C-x r j a` after opening another.

Comment: Could you point me to where I can find an explanation of what this is doing? Also, does this seem like the right way to do what I want to do (basically just have a persistent window set up upon connection)?

Comment: @phils This is very close.  But one weird quirk is that after doing this I can not quit emacs the normal way (or at all). I'd love to learn more about frameset, is there a way?

Comment: I can only point you at the library code itself. As you can see with `C-h k` the two commands are calling `frameset-to-register` and `frameset--jump-to-register` respectively. Ultimately they are using `frameset-save` and `frameset-restore`.